# Why do mathematicians not talk about $n$-contravariant antisymmetric tensors? (Contravariant $n$-forms)

Tags: differential-forms, tensors

In every course on differential geometry one is introduced to the concept of  vectors ($(1,0)$-tensors), one forms ($(0,1)$-tensors), generic $(m,n)$-tensors and $n$-forms i.e. $(0,n)$-tensors that are totally antisymmetric. It turns out $n$-forms have a rich algebra and can be differentiated and integrated without a metric. The question is, why mathematicians do not talk about $(n,0)$-tensors that are totally antisymmetric? It seems to me one could define a wedge product for these objects completely analogous to the one on forms and maybe one could also define their derivative...would these object be of any interest?

Comment: They do; they're called polyvector fields, and they form what's called a Gerstenhaber algebra.

Comment: I imagine it has to do with their mapping properties. You can push forward vectors but not necessarily any vector field, where's you can pullback covectors and any form. The exterior derivative commutes with the pullback. I'm not sure what would happen with the exterior derivative and the push forward. I mean you can of course just define the exterior algebra of the tangent space, but maybe the exterior derivative you could define doesn't work with the push forward as nicely?

Comment: You can work with such tensors just as easily as we do with $n$-forms--if you have some metric.  In traditional differential forms literature, these tensors are avoided by suitably defining Hodge duality instead and working exclusively with forms.